# Ansible: How to parse and loop over a single line output containing line breaks?

Tags: parsing, ansible

I am using Ansible which will uses get method and registered output will be used as input for another block. The problem is, the output is getting passed as a whole instead of single lines.

**Output**

```yaml
- debug: msg="{{jsoncontent.content }}"
  msg: |-

    index
    abc-def-2020-01
    abc-def1-2020-02
    abc-def2-2020-03
    abc-def3-2020-04
    abc-def4-2020-05
```

And I use the following block with the above output (`with_items`) block.

**Example**

```yaml
- name: List shards
  uri:
    url: 'https://{{ hostname }}:{{ port }}/_cat/shards/{{ item }}?v&s=index,state:desc'
    method: GET
    headers:
      Authorization: 'Basic basicAuth'
    force_basic_auth: yes
    status_code: 200
    return_content: yes
    validate_certs: no
  ignore_errors: yes
  register: jsoncontent1
  with_items: "{{ jsoncontent.content[:6] }}"
```

It's passing the entire output block to the `item`. Is there a way where single lines are passed?

Thanks!

Comment: What you are getting is a string with new lines, split it: `jsoncontent.content.splitlines()`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the content will have every time a leading empty line and one header line, a minimal example playbook

```yaml
---
- hosts: localhost
  become: false
  gather_facts: false

  vars:

    jsoncontent:
      content: |-

        index
        abc-def-2020-01
        abc-def1-2020-02
        abc-def2-2020-03
        abc-def3-2020-04
        abc-def4-2020-05

  tasks:

  - name: Construct URL
    debug:
      msg: "https://example.com/_cat/shards/{{ item }}?v&s=index,state:desc"
    loop: "{{ jsoncontent.content.splitlines()[2:] }}"
```

will result into an output of

```yaml
TASK [Construct URL] *******************************************************
ok: [localhost] => (item=abc-def-2020-01) =>
  msg: https://example.com/_cat/shards/abc-def-2020-01?v&s=index,state:desc
ok: [localhost] => (item=abc-def1-2020-02) =>
  msg: https://example.com/_cat/shards/abc-def1-2020-02?v&s=index,state:desc
ok: [localhost] => (item=abc-def2-2020-03) =>
  msg: https://example.com/_cat/shards/abc-def2-2020-03?v&s=index,state:desc
ok: [localhost] => (item=abc-def3-2020-04) =>
  msg: https://example.com/_cat/shards/abc-def3-2020-04?v&s=index,state:desc
ok: [localhost] => (item=abc-def4-2020-05) =>
  msg: https://example.com/_cat/shards/abc-def4-2020-05?v&s=index,state:desc
```

It is `loop`ing over the output `content` by [split the string into a list of lines via Python Method `.splitlines()`](https://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/str/splitlines.html) and drop the first two lines via [Python Slice Notation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/509295/6771046). See also [`split` filter – split a string into a list](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/split_filter.html).